# Correctly configuring Spring with security - Java

Tags: java, html, spring, security, spring-mvc

So I'm new to `Spring`, and learning in the way as I develop a web application using `Spring-Boot`.
Currently my page consists of two `html` pages: `index.html` and `login.html`. I'm also using `Spring-Security`.

Here's my current `MvcConfig`:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

The way the website is designed, an user goes  to the url http://localhost:8080, then he/she is presented with the initial page, there's a `login` tab there where he/she can log in, and move to the `dashboard` view (which I will add later). 
However, when I load the initial, the page is totally misconfigured (css / js / images resources aren't loaded).  After I go to http://localhost:8080/login, perform the login and everything works again.

Therefore, any url of the form http://localhost:8080 is to be allowed (`index.html`), but anything else would require login.
Here's my `Spring-Security` config:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
 }
```

How can I correctly configure my webpage?

*** Notes:
  * I currently don't have any Controller class.

Comment: add permitAll to css, js, image `http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers("/", "/index", "/**/*.js", ""/**/*.css"").permitAll()` 

because `anyRequest().authenticated()` make your request to html resource authorized.

or more easy, make style for login page

Comment: @ThangHoang could you better formulate your answer?

Comment: add permitAll to css, js, image 
`http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers("/", "/index", "/**/*.js", ""/**/*.css"").permitAll()` 

because `anyRequest().authenticated()` make your request to html resource authorized.

or more easy, make style for login page. no depend on static resource.

Comment: @ThangHoang Could you add that in an answer?

Comment: @philippe avoid using regexMatchers unless your application really is dependant on ultra complex dynamic url patterns. It is a lot more work to manage it then. Use antMatcher which is a lot simpler since it uses basic url inputs (/login, /admin, dashboard etc.) and it won't inteferre with any resource files you try and use. happy to provide answer if you go down this path.

Comment: @Aeseir I changes that to `antMatcher`. Could you provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem with regex matchers that i found is any resource loaded from your server you will need to account for in the mapping.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/login", "/admin").hasRole('ADMIN') // e.g. for pages that need to be authenticated
              .anyRequest().permitAll() // all the others will be accessable by all
              .and()
           .formLogin()
              .loginPage("/login")
              .permitAll()
              .and()
           .logout()
              .permitAll();
        }
}
```

The most simplest way to do matching is following steps:

1. Declare your resource files by overriding addResourceHandlers
2. Use antmatchers to handle url security (simpler and easier), unless you have extremely dynamic urls with critical parameter

Comment: For some reason its not applying the code format for me, if anyone can edit and fix it please do

Comment: Aeseir, how to add an `'ADMIN'` role?

Comment: What do you mean? How did you allocate roles to your users that will be authenticated?

Comment: I hope it also helped you understand security a bit more

Answer (score 1):

sorry guy, I will try to make it clear

`anyRequest().authenticated()` make your request to html resource need to authorized. You only permitAll to '/' & '/login'

so, add permitAll to css, js, image too
`http
  .authorizeRequests()
    .regexMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**/*.js", "/**/*.css").permitAll()`

or more easy, make a style for login page. no depend on other static resource.

Comment: I tried that ... first the `**` doesn't work. So the results were the same as before.